# Tab View initialization issues

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a tab view, separating the tabs "Stopwatch" and Timer." These are controlled by ClockViewController.m and h.

My issue is that the stopwatch is initializing just fine. My code for what it should do when the program opens works. However, my code for the timer does not.

Relevant code for ClockViewController.m:

Initializing ClockViewController:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
        if (startedSW == FALSE)
        {
            [self initializeTimer:nil];
        }

        if (isTimerRunning == FALSE)
        {
        [self initializeStopwatch:nil];
        }
    }

    return self;
}
```

initializeStopwatch (this one is the one that works fine):

```
- (void)initializeStopwatch:(id)sender
{

    //Sets the timer to 0 all-around.
    [lblSWTime setStringValue:@"XX:XX:XX"];
    [lblTimeSinceLastLap setStringValue:@"00:00:00"];
}
```

initializeTimer (the non-working one):

```
- (void)initializeTimer:(id)sender
{
    //Set up the panel to properly be ready to go.
    [btnTimerPause setEnabled:NO];
    [lblTimerTime setStringValue:@"59:59"];
    [lblTimerTime setHidden:NO];
    [lblTimerMillisecs setHidden:NO];

    //Sets up the minutes pop-up button to have the correct options in it.
    int minutesIntToAdd = 1;
    NSString *minutesIntToAddString;
    for (int i = 1; i < 60; i++)
    {
        //Adds 1-59 to the pop-up button.
        minutesIntToAddString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", minutesIntToAdd];
        [btnMinutesButton addItemWithTitle:minutesIntToAddString];
        minutesIntToAdd++;
    }

    //Sets up the seconds pop-up button to have the correct options in it.
    int secondsIntToAdd = 1;
    NSString *secondsIntToAddString;
    for (int j = 1; j < 60; j++)
    {
        //Adds 1-59 to the pop-up button.
        secondsIntToAddString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", secondsIntToAdd];
        [btnSecondsButton addItemWithTitle:secondsIntToAddString];
        secondsIntToAdd++;
    }
}
```

My issue is that none of the code in initializeTimer is working. It's not running it when the xib is loaded / initialized.

I know this question is confusing, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger?

Comment: Did you put in some break points to make sure the code is getting reached?

Comment: Michael: I've tried using the debugger but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Joe: I don't understand what the break points are and / or how they work. I tried an NSLog, and the NSLog comes through, though twice for some reason instead of just once. I'm only calling [self initializeTimer:nil] once though.

Comment: Meh, I managed to sort of fix it. Not sure what I did though, so anybody who finds this in Google with a similar issue, you're effed. :P

Comment: Learn to use the debugger. It's a basic and vital tool. It's like telling us you're building a house but don't know how to use a tape measure. You *must* be able to examine the state of your running code to get useful information about why it's not working (much less to ask others for help since we have *no earthly idea* without the same information).